# Join 2 type list in python by index

Tags: python

I want to ask how to join 2 different type list (string and integer) by index

```
list1 = ['a','p','p','l','e']
list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5'] # i want to change this into integer
```

my output is

```
['a1', 'p2', 'p3', 'l4', 'e5']
```

my expected output

```
['a',1, 'p',2, 'p',3, 'l',4, 'e',5]
```

and that is my code

```
list1 = ["a","p","p","l","e"] 
list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5']

print ("The original list 1 is : " + str(list1))
print ("The original list 2 is : " + str(list2))

res = [i + j for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]


print ("The list after element concatenation is : " + str(res))
```

Comment: I linked duplicates that should address all the direct facets of your question, but you might also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists.

Comment: I would suggest a list of tuples instead, e.g. `[('a', 1), ('p', 2)]`. Easier to iterate over and get corresponding pairs at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in function from `itertool` for this:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([i,int(j)] for i,j in zip(list1, list2)))
#['a', 1, 'p', 2, 'p', 3, 'l', 4, 'e', 5]
```

Comment: You would want to `zip(list1,[int(el) for el in list2])` instead of list2, to get ints

Comment: yep just updated